# Cluster Markers with CartoDB

Tags: carto, clustering, carto-js, markers

Is there an easy generic way to cluster Markers with CartoDB?

[image]

Comment: Have you already checked CartoDB support forum? This seem pretty specific to their platform even though in theory you could also solve that by a pure PostGIS algorithm (In which case it will be a pretty straightforward one)

Comment: There is an example of clustering with CartoDB [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8306637) as well as an example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8675947). Links are courtesy of @iriberri

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do it with the built in CartoDB map creator, you can definitely do it with your own JavaScript webapp.

Follow the CartoDB examples here to make a map: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html

And use the Leaflet Marker Cluster plugin: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster